# Trying to remove www and force HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I'm trying to force HTTPS for every request on my portfolio and also remove the WWW from the url. I've managed to remove the WWW from requests however when I try force HTTPS I'm given an error of "Too many redirects"

This is my htaccess file:

```html
# remove www. from HTTPS requests
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(patrickwhitehouse\.pw)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1/$0 [R,L]

# redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(patrickwhitehouse\.pw)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1/$0 [R,L]
```

If I manually put https://myurl.com, it works however when I visit another page, the HTTPS goes back to HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is redirecting WWW. not removing it. Here is a code I've been using for the same issue.

```
### WWW & HTTPS

#Remove WWW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

#Ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```